# How to search for certain number of letter within a text file with PHP?

Tags: php, file, search

I have a large text file with names, location and date of birth of lots of people. I need to find names based on character size. How can I do this with PHP?

In the text file, data is organised like this:

```
    Name-Location                                 ID                   DOB
    Bob-LA                                        110                  12/01/1987
    Lia-CA                                        111                  11/09/1984
    Neil-LA                                       112                  17/10/1982
    Emon-CA                                       113                  07/12/1991
    Elita-CA                                      113                  13/06/1983
    Ron-CA                                        114                  16/02/1979
    and so on
```

Now I wish to search for people with certain character name and with same location (say I wish to find all the people whose name has 4 letter and are from CA [Emon-CA]). How can I do that?
I can normally search through a file using PHP, where I know the string I am looking for. But here I actually don't know how to set the condition to show up my desired results. Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you manage to write the ID/DOB and names aligned like that? If you have a text file? or are they all in one line?

Comment: Open the file with `csv-file` and run through the results, stripping -CA, and if `-CA` exists in the string, count the characters in the name, and if that are 4 store it..

Comment: My advice for you would be to get the data in a csv format and insert it into a database. It will make your life a lot easier. If you, however, chose to still use the text file, you can try using regex to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know how the texts are well formatted, I was provided with it, and asked to search name based on location and character size. I can certainly search based on location only, but unable to search using number of characters. The text file has more than a thousand people's name :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$filename = "log.txt";

foreach ( new TextFileFilterIterator($filename) as $line ) {
    list($name, $location, $id, $dob) = $line;
    if (strlen($name) == 4 && $location == "CA") {
        echo implode(",", $line), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Emon,CA,113,07/12/1991
```

Class Used

```
class TextFileFilterIterator extends ArrayIterator {
    private $filter;

    function __construct($filename) {
        parent::__construct(array_filter(array_map("trim", file($filename))));
    }

    public function current() {
        $c = array_filter(explode("   ", parent::current()));
        list($n, $l) = explode("-", array_shift($c));
        array_unshift($c, $n, $l);
        return array_map("trim", $c);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I only need to print the name. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using regular expressions, something like this:

```
// assume $text contains the contents of your text file
$namelength = 4; // change this as needed
$location = 'CA'; // again, change as needed
```

If you just want to count the results

```
$count = preg_match_all('|^\s*([\w]{'.$namelength.'})-'.$location.'\s*(\d+)\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})$|',$text,$matches);
```

Otherwise, If you want to do something with each match:

```
if(preg_match_all('|^\s*([\w]{'.$namelength.'})-'.$location.'\s*(\d+)\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})$|',$text,$matches)){
    foreach($matches as $match){
        $name = $match[1];
        $id = $match[3];
        $dob = $match[4];
        // Do something with each name.
    }
}
```